# How to make PM smaller than other characters in textbox in Sketch?

Tags: text, sketch-app

I have this textbox here. And I just do not understand the magic, why "PM" is smaller? Though it seems just normal text on the left side.

[image]

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem, however I just thought I'd bring it up anyway. There's actually no such time as 19 PM.  It should be written as 7 PM.  You shouldn't mix up 19:00 (in 24 hour time notation) with the AM and PM time notation.  PM means *post meridiem", which is Latin for "after midday", and so you can't say 19 hours after midday because it wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I'm not a Sketch User</sub>

---

Typically in most apps **layers** don't resize their names in the panel/list.. I mean the layer name doesn't become 30pts tall simply because the text is set to 30pts. That's not how User Interfaces work.

Chances are the text is set at a different size. Select it with the text editing tool and then check it's size.

Comment: its size (not it's) is also possibly a subscript for the font, if the program supports that feature for fonts.